# How do I know the length of instruction in assembly?

Tags: assembly, architecture, x86

I have come cross a segment of code like this:

```
jmp 0x26 #2 bytes
popl %esi #1 bytes
movl %esi,0x8(%esi) # 3 bytes
movb $0x0,0x7(%esi) # 4 bytes

.....

.string \"/bin/sh\" #8 bytes
```

I wonder how dose the author know how many bytes for each instruction?

Comment: Either from experience, from looking it up in the Intel docs, or from generating an asm listing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love how the first comment you get is essentially the answer... but it's not in the answer box! So I'll expand upon that.

So, as you've gathered, you have to "know" - and you know this by looking up the instruction in the Intel manual.

I'll give you a straightforward example If you want to work out the size of say `mov rax, [rsp+8]` you could assemble this in nasm:

```
 BITS 64
 mov rax, [rsp+8]
```

With the following command:

```
 nasm -fbin test.asm -o test.bin
```

Examining test.bin, you'll see in Hex it is:

```
 48 8B 44 24 08
```

Here `8B` represents the `mov` instruction. The `48` preceding it is a REX prefix with the `w` property set (indicating a 64-bit target). The last byte, `08`, represents the displacement from the previous register, which is `24`, which indicates `esp` (except the targets are wide, because the `REX` prefix tells us so). Finally, `44` represents `eax*2`, which would be a 64-bit wide field.

The exact addressing mode used here is pretty complicated, but safe to say that common ones can quickly be worked out. For example, the 32-bit equivalent (`mov eax, [esp+4]`) is the 4-byte `8B 44 24 04`.